# Determine if a Named Range exists, if so copy it, if not move on

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to determine if a Named Range exists in my spreadsheet. If it doesn't exist, I do not want to set a variable to it. If it does exist, I want to set a variable to it.

I have tried the following, but I can't seem to get the wording quite right.

```
If RangeExist("Table1") <> 0 Then
    Set QuBuild = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Features").Range("Table1")
Else
End If
```

If the named range "Table1" exists, I want to set it to the variable "QuBuild" to do something with later on (paste the table into word). If it doesn't exist, I don't want to set "QuBuild"equal to anything.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: It looks like you're working with tables. If so, I'd recommend using [`ListObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject).

Comment: Hi @BigBen, well I just named my range "Table1" because it is a small section of a table. I am considering it just a normal range.

Comment: Ah ok, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer for Named Ranges specifically.

```
Public Sub ExampleUsage()
    Debug.Print DoesNameRangeExist("Table1")
End Sub

Public Function DoesNameRangeExist(ByVal NameOfRange As String) As Boolean
    Dim NamedRanges    As Names
    Dim Name           As Name

    Set NamedRanges = ThisWorkbook.Names
    DoesNameRangeExist = False

    For Each Name In NamedRanges
        If Name.Name = NameOfRange Then
            DoesNameRangeExist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Loop all worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Loop all tables - Listobjects
        For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects

            If tbl.Name = "Table1" Then

            End If

        Next tbl

    Next ws

End Sub
```

**OR:**

```
Sub test()

    Dim strNameRange
    Dim ws As Worksheets

    For Each strNameRange In ThisWorkbook.Names

        If strNameRange.Name = "Table1" Then

        End If

    Next strNameRange

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Error 1004, this also works well :) I never normally use Option Explicit, what are it's main use cases?

Comment: @PKen here's the  [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) documentation. It's recommended to always use it. In the VB Editor, click *Tools* > *References* > *Require Variable Declaration* to set this as default.